# Plasma Mode in Type I Superconductors above and below $T_{c}$

Tags: electromagnetism, condensed-matter, superconductivity, plasmon

Consider a type I superconductor above and below $T_{c}$. Do the longitudinal oscillations of the electromagnetic vector potential below $T_{c}$ correspond to the well-known plasmon mode for a normal metal? What are the similarities/differences?

Comment: If you provide more details, add equations, references or something more, it will be interesting

Comment: Thanks. I finally found the answer, though. Turns out it's the same. See, for instance, Nagaosa's book on Condensed Matter. Unfortunately, this is not a full answer and writing it will be too much. So, if anyone is interested, I've quoted the reference. The idea is to write the full action for a superconductor along with the electromagnetic terms, and then look at the resulting modes. The plasma mode at high energy remains unaffected (wrt a normal metal), while the other two electromagnetic modes produce Meissner effect in a superconductor below $T_c$.